# Setup headless integration using the Minimum Access profile

Tags: integration, connected-apps

I'm doing some testing using the new Salesforce Minimum Access profile.  I'm using a connected app in conjunction with this and I'm using Postman to get an access token.
See details about the user here
[image: Postman]

And the obfuscated user details

[image: Integration User]

What could be stopping me here getting a token? I'm using the client credentials flow, and i've also set up this user as the running user inside the Connected app i'm using, even though it doesn't show in the image.  The user has the required profile and the required ur license.  Anyone with an idea what to check next?

And the Connected App

[image: Connected App]

Comment: so the client credentials user is a) active and b) has API-enabled permission?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow: no client credentials user enabled](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393851/oauth-2-0-client-credentials-flow-no-client-credentials-user-enabled)

Comment: @cropredy yes and yes

Comment: @indentigral unfortunately no.  I've made sure that the user is correct, and he has the correct permissions and is set as the running user in the configuration for the connected app. as shown in the screengrab.

Comment: @akamid Wrong `Run As...`

Comment: possible: client credentials flow doesn't support refresh OAuth scope - remove;

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an answer.  I figured out that the only thing I needed to do was to reset the security token for the integration user and append the new token to the existing password.  Funny how it's always this trick, I thought I didn't need the token since I have IP Ranges set in this org, but go figure :)

Comment: Client Credentials flow [is explicitly designed to run without a username or password](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_client_credentials_flow.htm&type=5), you can remove them from your call.